# Change commandButton Label style

Tags: css, primefaces

I have a Primefaces commandButton

```
<p:commandButton value="..." action="..." styleClass="myButton"/>
```

with a custom css-class

```
.mybutton{
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     width: 200px;
}
```

I want to override some attributes of the button label's class, which is

```
.ui-button-text-icon-left .ui-button-text
```

What should I write in order to just customize labels of class 'mybutton' and not all buttons in my web app?

---

I'm using JSF2.2, PF 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your rule to affect only buttons which have all of the mentioned classes, use this

```
.mybutton.ui-button-text-icon-left.ui-button-text {
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     width: 200px;
}
```

`<p:commandButton>` is rendered as `<button>` with nested `<span>` which contains a label. Something like this

```
<button ... class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-priority-primary mybutton" ...>
    <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">My button</span>
</button>
```

So, if you are actually trying to style the label, then the CSS rule should be

```
.mybutton .ui-button-text {
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     width: 200px;
}
```

This way, it targets the component having class `ui-button-text` which is nested under component with class `mybutton`.

Comment: I had tried this, without success. Apparently I have to write .mybutton .ui-button-text

Comment: Yes, because `<p:commandButton>` is rendered as `<button>` (having `mybutton` class) with nested `<span>` (having `ui-button-text` class). I'll update my answer

Comment: All basic css. Better take a step back from jsf development and spend some time reading about css